# Passing in a querystring with a space?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

I have an action like this:

```
public ActionResult UserDetails(string id)
{
}

context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In another view i have a list with users from the standard membership management in .net
Idea is that you click on a username to show the details and this works, only if the username is in one word. I recently encountered a username that looks like this:

Steven C.H. Andersson

So i use this to produce the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.UserName, "UserDetails", new { controller = "Security", id = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Model.UserName) })
```

But when i click on it, i get: HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found

If i click on a normal username that is one word, it works like a charm.

I assume that the route config is not understanding this request, question is how to get it to work?

**Update**

Link:

```
<a href="/Security/UserDetails/Steven%2bC.H.%2bAndersson">Steven C.H. Andersson</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the rendered link -- just in case it's not what we expect?

Comment: Just a thought: Did you try *not* encoding the username yourself, i.e. just `..., id = Model.UserName })`? MVC is often pretty smart in handling such things itself, using its own standard encoding/decoding.

Comment: Yes, tested without encoding as well. Same result.

Comment: Your encoding is wrong. It should be either `.../UserDetails/Steven%20bC.H.%20Andersson` or `.../UserDetails/Steven+bC.H.+Andersson`

Comment: If you were to remove the spaces and link to `StevenC.H.Andersson`, what would it do?  I know it wouldn't be a valid user name, but I'm curious as to whether you'd get a `401.11` or some other error.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding is obviously wrong, as it encodes spaces as "%2b", which is "+". You're passing not a query string argument, but a part of path, so you need to use HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode()

Comment: I tested it but that results in this: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%). I also added [ValidateInput(false)] but i keep getting the same thing.

Comment: Then probably it is not possible. Anyway, it is a bad idea to pass user name as identifier, as it could be not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is how I solved it, but I am not sure it is the best way. I am keen to hear a more elegant solution.

In the view file:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.UserName, "UserDetails", new { controller = "Security", id = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Model.UserName)) })
```

In the controller file:

```
id = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(id))
```